# Вывод сообщений как Вконтакте

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Реализовал на сайте возможность отправки личных сообщений и хочу сделать, чтоб сообщения выводились как, например, Вконтакте. То есть как мне вывести сообщения виде чата, только я и получатель!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все гениальное - просто:  
первое, что понадобится - общее хранилище сообщений. У каждого сообщения свой уникальный идентификатор (в лоб - авто инкремент).

```
id  msg_title   msg_body   other .....
```

и собственно сама история переписки:

```
id   user1    user2   msg_id
```

Сама переписка контролируется примерно так:
при отправке сообщения оно записывается в хранилище тут мы получаем id этого сообщения.
потом записываем это сообщение сразу 2м юзерам: т.е

```
 id отправитель получатель msg_id   
 id получатель  отправитель msg_id
```

и получаем историю переписки

```
where user_1=current_user and user_2=с_кем_мы_переписываемся
```

P.S: сразу оговорюсь для Hi-load от SQL баз придется отказаться...

Comment: Почему же отказаться на hi-load от SQL? Избавиться от JOIN`ов и грамотные индексы поставить достаточно, разве нет?

Comment: `Timestamp` еще напрашивается, поскольку сортировать вывод сообщений по `id` некорректно.

Comment: И если можно пример кода вывода

Comment: История переписки таблицы `о_о`

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю какие таблицы должны быть в sql , напишите полностью структуру!